# Is there a way to pass a method WITH parameters as a new action?

Tags: c#

Its possible to do

```
using System;

Action action = new Action(Console.WriteLine);

action(); //will write a empty line
```

but is there a way to pass a method with parameters e.g.

```
using System;

Action action = new Action(Console.WriteLine("Hello World")); //This doesn't work

action(); //want it to write a line which will say "Hello World"
```

Comment: You should be able to pass in a lambda expression () => Console.Writeline("hello")

Comment: If you know the method to be invoked and all its parameters at compile-time, why not simply *directly* call it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Action action = new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello World"));
```

or as mentioned @JeroenMostert

```
Action action = () => Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
```

Comment: The `new Action()` wrapping is unnecessary; the compiler does that on its own.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this also

```
Action<int> print = ConsolePrint;
print(10);
```

---

```
static void ConsolePrint(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

or you can do this also

```
Action<int> print = (i)=>  Console.WriteLine(i);
print(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic action like this

```
Action<string> writeLine = Console.WriteLine;
writeLine("hello");
```